# When deploying with Firebase hosting, I get hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from [subschema 0],[subschema 1]

Tags: firebase, web-deployment, firebase-hosting

Deploying an application to Firebase hosting, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error: 400, hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from [subschema 0],[subschema 1]
```

This occurs with a simple configuration like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/*/*",
        "destination": "index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This configuration does work when serving locally.

Answer (score 17):

Apparently, the error indicates that I should put a '/' in front of 'index.html'. Then it works for local and remote deploy.

Comment: didn't help me. I was using a function called ssr instead of a static index.html.file for deploying with Angular Universal, eg `"destination": "ssr"`. Any idea what the error actually means?

Comment: concerning my problem: it should be: `"function": "ssr"`