# HTTP Error: 400, hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from [subschema 0 ],[subschema 1]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

While using `firebase deploy` Im getting following error:

`Error: HTTP Error: 400, hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from [subschema 0
],[subschema 1]`

[image]

What can cause this?

My functions file `index.js`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import App from './app/containers/App';

const index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');

const app = express();

app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderToString(<App />);
  const finalHtml = index.replace('app', html);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(finalHtml);
});

export const ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);

exports.someCustomFunction1 = functions.database.ref(...).onWrite(...);
exports.someCustomFunction2 = functions.database.ref(...).onWrite(...);
```

And `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "ssrapp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760199/when-deploying-with-firebase-hosting-i-get-hosting-rewrites0-is-not-exactly-o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When deploying with Firebase hosting, I get hosting.rewrites\[0\] is not exactly one from \[subschema 0\],\[subschema 1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760199/when-deploying-with-firebase-hosting-i-get-hosting-rewrites0-is-not-exactly-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration for rewriting a URL to a Cloud Function requires a pair of `source` and `function`.  Currently you are showing a pair of `source` and `destination`, so you should probably just change `destination` to `function`.  [Please see the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_hosting_requests_to_your_function) for more details.